# Iterating using for-each loop over result set

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve over ressultset using for-each loop. My code is as follows:

```
for(String s:list){
    while(rs.next){
        for(int i=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount.getColumn){
            //my code

        }
    }
'
```

From here I am writing my data to xml.

list contains four Distinct values which I am retrieving from database using distinct query.

but my for loop is not iterating for distinct values. It is iterating only for one value which it getting first from list. Please help. I want to know why I am not able to iterate over all distinct values in list. Also please suggest how I can iterate for each value present in list

Comment: Why do you operate on a `ResultSet` when you already have read the database (`list`)? Very unclear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consuming a `ResultSet` with `while (rs.next()) { ... }` will consume the *whole* result set. Embedding that into an outer loop

```
for (...) {
    while (rs.next()) { ... }
}
```

will then consume the *whole* result set in the first loop run (of the outer loop). This outer loop will run for each element of your list, but the entry condition of the while loop (`rs.next()`) will now be always `false`.

Comment: could you please suggest what I can do to resolve this problem..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like this when you call

```
for(String s:list){
  while(rs.next()) {
    for(int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount().getColumn()){
        //my code

    }
  }
}
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: sorry I didn't got you

Comment: edited again, i think the method you need to call is getMetaData(), you cann't just access the fields directly

Comment: Forgot to mention I have used metadata as getting column count is possible only through metadata